# json_encode($list, 15) - what is 15?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

I have noticed, that laravel blade `@json($list)` directive (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade)

is being converted into

```
<?php echo json_encode($list, 15, 512) ?>
```

Whait is `15`?

I don't see this option among available options

> options
>   Bitmask consisting of JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, JSON_HEX_QUOT, JSON_HEX_TAG, JSON_HEX_AMP, JSON_HEX_APOS, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR, JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR.

PS
you can try to decode more directives like that

```
{{ '@json($list)'}}
```

Comment: Those [`JSON_*` constants](https://www.php.net/manual/json.constants.php) are all integers. The `$options` argument is an integer bitmask. You don't need to use the constants if you know the value you want

Answer (score 5):

It's the result of [OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bitwise_operators)ing these options:

```
JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_TAG
```

`15` is `1111` in binary, dumping all JSON constants we can see

```
foreach (get_defined_constants() as $c => $v) {
    if (substr($c, 0, 4) !== "JSON") continue;

    echo "$c ".decbin($v)."\n";
}
```

That

```
JSON_HEX_TAG 1
JSON_HEX_AMP 10
JSON_HEX_APOS 100
JSON_HEX_QUOT 1000
...
```

Those options combined give the resulting number `1111` or `15` in decimal.